# How to integrate Tinymce with angular 4.0

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am getting error that **SimpleTinyComponent is not an NgModule**

Copied the sample code from 
"https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/"

Created one component for tinymce where I based the basic setup code of TinyMCE then on Basic component HTML used the selector of tinymce.

Basic.component.ts is having only console.log() for now.

I am not able to get where i am going wrong.

I need to use tinymce for multiple textarea on same page.

> tinymce.component.ts

```
    import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  AfterViewInit,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-tiny',
  template: `<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>`
})
export class SimpleTinyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() elementId: String;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }
}
```

> basic.component.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Embedding TinyMCE</h3>
  <simple-tiny
    [elementId]="'my-editor-id'"
    (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)"
  >
  </simple-tiny>
</div>
```

> App.module.ts

```
import {SimpleTinyComponent} from './component/email/tinymce.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    modalComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SimpleTinyComponent
]
```

Comment: You are adding `SimpleTinyComponent` to the `imports` section of your `NgModule`, but it is a `Component` and should be added to the `declarations` section.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp this was the mistake